# How to make my spray project into a standalone eclipse rcp application?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, spray-dsl

I created an emf model and also a spray project. I am able to start the spray project over "Run as.." as an eclipse application and i will get an editor that depends on my emf model.

Now i would like to integrate this editor into a part of an eclipse rcp application. How can i achieve that? I tried adding the spray and emf project to my feature project as a plug in but i do not know which class the part should refer to. Is this even the right way?

How can i make my spray editor be a part of my rcp application?

Comment: I am confused. Spray is for building web services... what does this have to do with Eclipse RCP, which is for desktop applications? If this is to be used by developers, why can't they just use Eclipse?

Comment: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/spray/

Comment: I should have mentioned it. Sorry.

Comment: I have changed the tag, to avoid confusing people.